How to I use an Rcpp function within an R function when building an R package?
I am trying to build an R library with an R function that call an Rcpp function. I used to call this Rcpp function through sourceCpp and it worked well.
When trying to make the R library using roxygen etc, I got
  "_myPackage_myFunction" not available for .Call() for package "myPackage"

From online tutorial http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Rcpp.html#rcpp-package and https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-package.pdfI found out that
useDynLib(mypackage)
importFrom(Rcpp, evalCpp)

Should be stated in the NAMESPACE file. However, this would produce an error when installing the library:
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘myPackage’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/home/me/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/00LOCK-myPackage/00new/myPackage/libs/myPackage.so':
  /home/marc/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/00LOCK-MSCA2/00new/MSCA2/libs/MSCA2.so: undefined symbol: _ZTIN3tbb4taskE
Error: loading failed

I couldn't find out what was the problem and I would welcome any help or suggestions
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.3.3 (2024-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.10.0 
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.10.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

time zone: Europe/London
tzcode source: system (glibc)

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] devtools_2.4.5 usethis_3.0.0 


You could start from what the package documentation suggests and use the supported and documented function Rcpp.package.skeleton() to get a working package where you can then add your function in src/.  The RStudio IDE also has a helper.  Then run Rcpp::compileAttributes() and your package should build.  The function Rcpp::sourceCpp() is never used inside a package.
